# Autosys Job to send email alerts on some condition

Tags: linux, autosys

I have a task to send email notification when the SQL query yields particular result every 1 hour on unix system.
I have tried the below but somewhere I am missing something

```
insert_job: job name
job_type: SQL
machine:xxxx
owner:xxxx
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "00:00, 01:00 .... 23:00"
SQL command: SQL query
connect string: Oracle connection
destination file: destination location for o/p log
send notification : 1
notification emailaddress : team email list
notification msg: message
max run alarm : 10
alarm if fail: 1
alarm if terminated : 1
```